# Solve KKT conditions of the following problem

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm having problems solving the following

$\min f(X) = −3x^2 +y^2 +2z^2 +2(x+y+z) $

subject to $c(X):=x^2+y^2+z^2−1=0$

Now, I get the KKT:

$-6x +2 -2\lambda x = 0 $

$2y +2 -2\lambda y = 0 $

$4z +2 -2\lambda z = 0 $

together with the constraint $c(X):=x^2+y^2+z^2−1=0$.

The problem is that I cannot find a suitable point, (or pair $x,  \lambda$) which solve these conditions.

Any ideas ? The main problem I think it is that I have a quadratic constraint that makes everything harder

Comment: You can solve your linear system for $(x,y,z)$ in terms of $\lambda$, then plug in the constraint to get an equation for $\lambda$.

Comment: I did that as first thing, but then I get the exponent of $\lambda$ up to the 6th, and this makes things more complicated

Comment: I might not make it more complicated. It is might be exactly how complicated your problem is. Any solution of that equation gives a stationary point.

Comment: The problem is that I get (WolframAlpha helped me) 2 real roots for $\lambda$, both of them negative, but they must be greater or equal to zero by definition, so I don't know how to proceed

Comment: why do they have to be greater than or equal to zero?

Comment: It's simply not true that the Lagrange multiplier for an equality constraint must be $\geq 0$.  The sign requirement comes in when you have an inequality constraint.

Comment: It's relatively easy to find two Lagrange points using symbolic computation software (and it would appear to be quite painful by hand.)  What's the point of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be hard to find the values for $x,y,z,$ and $\lambda$ analytically. To my best knowledge, this is generally not possible for optimization problems with quadratic cost functions with a quadratic constraints.

Matlab's fmincon function gives me $x = -0.9660, y = -0.1986, z = -0.1657,$ and $\lambda = 4.0352.$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plot of the function from different angles. It seems like it has a unique global minimum and a unique global maximum, consistent with the Lagrangian having two stationary points:
[image]